# Full Calendar Get current date

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I've been learning Ruby over the last year and I'm very new to JS so I'll try to explain this as best I can.

I am using [Adam Shaw's full calendar plugin](http://fullcalendar.io/). All I want to do is get the current month I am viewing (and use that to limit how far in the future or past a user can navigate, but that's not the problem).

I can get the current date, sort of. But, because of my lack of JS knowledge I'm not sure how to access the date.

Here is the relevant section of the config file,

```
viewRender: function(view){
  var maxDate = "<%= finish.strftime('%Y/%m/%d') %>";
  var currentDate = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
  console.log(currentDate);
  if (view.start > maxDate){
    header.disableButton('prev');

  }
}
```

When I inspect the console log I see this being output as I click through the months.

[image: console log]

So as you can see it is displaying the current date in view. My question is how do I access the `_d` bit of the `Moment` variable so I can use it?

My understanding would be that the Moment is class instance and the stuff in the dropdown is like its attributes, would this be a correct interpretation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FullCalendar's `getDate` returns a moment object, so you need [moment's `toDate()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/) method to get date out of it.

So, in you code try:

```
console.log(currentDate.toDate());
```

and that should return a date object.

Answer (score 4):

To get the current date of the calendar, do:

```
var tglCurrent = $('#YourCalendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
```

This will return the date as a `moment` object. You can then format it as a string in the usual date format like so:

```
var tgl=moment(tglCurrent).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

For the actual time, use the format: `YYYY-MM-DD LTS`

Answer (score 1):

```
var moment = $('#YourCalendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
var calDate = moment.format('DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm'); //Here you can format your Date
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it’s always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: depends on your version of fullcalendar. do u get an js-error?